# How to pass params dynamicaly from template to ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to pass params dynamically to ListView via URL:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from objects.models import Object


class UserObjectsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'user_objects.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Object.objects.all()
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<int:pk>/', views.UserObjectsView.as_view(), name='user-objects')
]
```

template where I call this url:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'user-objects' %}{{ user.id }}">Objects</a></h3>
```

I want to pass this `user.id` dynamically, but right now it appers error:

> Reverse for 'user-objects' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['objects/user/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the parameters *in* the template, like:

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'user-objects' pk=user.id %}">Objects</a></h3>
```

Comment: Hmm, Okay, but how to get this value in ListView, I tried to rewrite queryset, like this:
`def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.GET.get('pk')
        print(user_id)` but it returns me None`

Comment: I found it `user_id = self.kwargs['pk']`, is it the best way ?

Comment: `self.request.GET` is for query parameters.. you are looking for `self.kwargs.get("pk")`

Comment: @JoEark: the value is not in `self.request.GET`, since that contains the parameters in the *querystring*. As you just found out, these parameters are in `self.kwargs`.